# Select All Part Numbers that Have Some Value in Two Different Rows

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

If I do a query:

SELECT PartNumber FROM Product_Options;

I get a result like this:

[image]

What I really need to do is select all from Product_Options where OptionName = 'Category' AND OptionValue = 'KID', OptionName = 'Category' AND OptionName = 'SKT'. OptionName must have those values in the SAME row.

I now I'm probably way off here but the query I tried resulted in a syntax error:

SELECT PartNumber FROM Product_Options WHERE OptionName = 'Category' AND OptionValue = 'KID', OptionName = 'Category' AND OptionValue = 'SKT';

If it actually worked, the above query would return 'CR5661' and whichever other PartNumbers had an OptionValue of KID and OptionValue of SKT

I'm not sure if I need to use a JOIN, but the idea is to select all part numbers where the category is KID and the category is also SKT all having the same PartNumber.

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `count(distinct OptionValue)` or `count(*)` if `OptionValue` is unique for each `PartNumber` and use the `where` to restrict the source to just the values you are looking for.

```
select PartNumber
from Product_Options
where OptionName = 'Category' 
  and (OptionValue = 'KID' or OptionValue = 'SKT')
group by PartNumber
having count(distinct OptionValue)>1
```

Comment: Will this query select PartNumber if OptionValue = 'KID' or OptionValue = 'SKT'? I only need to select PartNumber if OptionValue = 'KID' AND OptionValue = 'SKT'.

Comment: @GTSJoe Right, the `having count(distinct OptionValue)>1` makes sure it only returns `PartNumber` when it has more than one of `'KID'` or `'SKT'` and since we are only counting `distinct` values, we know that if it has more than 1, it has at least two, which means it has both of those values.